# How can I make parallel ant scripts easier to debug?

Tags: ant

Ant has a nifty  element but when used results in confusing messages. The output from Ant seems to consist of just the union of both sets of messages. Is there any way to separate these out or, at least, force Ant to serialize them as if they were run sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so, Ant is doing a FIFO.  I would advise printing the thread ID along with message to help make sense of the messages.

Comment: The messages are generated by Ant itself, such as from exec calls.